# Windows Defender Fails To Update Definitions (even via manual download & install)

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-defender

My Windows 10 LTSC 2019 installation can't seem to update Windows Defender definitions.  Although there are countless discussions online about definition update failures, I've tried every solution I could find but none seem to make any difference.  Here's what I've tried:

- To start, here's the error shown by Windows Update:
  [image: pic]

(KB2267602, Error 0x80070643).  Note that all other Windows Updates have been successfully installed - Defender definitions is the only "pending update" it finds.

- The Windows Update troubleshooter doesn't find any issues
- Trying to update via command-line (administrator):

> "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MPCMDRUN.exe" -RemoveDefinitions -All
>
> "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MPCMDRUN.exe" -SignatureUpdate

Yields error hr=80070643. screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

... with MpCmdRun.log showing:

```
MpEnsureProcessMitigationPolicy: hr = 0x1
Start: MpSignatureUpdate()
Calling MpUpdateStartEx with option 0x1
Update started 
Search Started (MU/WU update) (Path: https://fe2.update.microsoft.com/v6/)...
Search Completed 
Download Started...
Download Completed 
Download Completed 
Installation Started...
Update failed with hr: 0x80070643
Installation Completed 
Update failed with hr: 0x80070643
Search Started (Direct HTTP) (Path: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=851034&clcid=0x409&arch=x64&eng=0.0.0.0&avdelta=0.0.0.0&asdelta=0.0.0.0&prod=77BDAF73-B396-481F-9042-AD358843EC24&ostype=0&signaturetype=0&beta=1&plat=4.18.1907.4&OsVersion=10.0.17763.107)...
Download Started...
Time Info - ?Tue ?Jul ?30 ?2019 13:41:58 Download Completed 
Installation Started...
Update failed with hr: 0x80070005
Installation Completed 
Search Started (Direct HTTP) (Path: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=870379&clcid=0x409&arch=x64&eng=0.0.0.0&avdelta=0.0.0.0&asdelta=0.0.0.0&prod=77BDAF73-B396-481F-9042-AD358843EC24&ostype=0&signaturetype=0&beta=1&plat=4.18.1907.4&OsVersion=10.0.17763.107)...
Installation Completed 
Update completed with hr: 0x80070643
ERROR: Signature Update failed with hr=80070643
```

- Tried renaming SoftwareDistribution & CatRoot (per https://blog.pcrisk.com/windows/12817-windows-update-error-0x80070643).  No change.
- Trying to update from the Windows Security dialog:

[image: screenshot]

, it just shows "Checking for updates..." but then no change (i.e. definitions date never gets updated).

- Manually downloading & installing mpam-fe.exe from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/definitions has no effect (no error or success message shown, Windows Security never shows the updated definitions)
- sfc /scannow doesn't fix it
- DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth doesn't fix it
- I tried completely reinstalling Windows on top of my current installation, but the behavior is the same
- Windows Defender itself is functional (i.e. I can do a Quick scan, and it completes) - it's only the ability to update that's broken.
- I don't have any other antivirus/antispyware software installed
- I used msconfig to reboot with Selective Startup, all non-Microsoft services disabled.  Still failed to update, showing this error:

[image: screenshot]

- The PC is not connected to an AD domain.
- I tried installing a fresh copy of Windows from the same installation media in a VM, then updating the definitions (to verify that the issue isn't i.e. Microsoft posting a corrupt definitions installer).  I also fully updated this VM via Windows Update, removed the definitions with mpcmdrun.exe per above, & updated them again.  This worked, confirming that it's not an issue of Microsoft posting a corrupt update file.

At this point I'm at a loss, as I've spent nearly 7 hours going through HowTos, KBs, & forum threads - all of which either suggest some combination of the fixes I've already tried or stop at a dead-end.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to install cumulative updates?  Is this device connected to a AD domain?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Edited & added above.

Comment: You run the `MPCMDRUN.exe -RemoveDefinitions -All` and `SignatureUpdate` as Administrator (sorry if this is obvious, but wasn't stated).

Comment: What security software do you have installed other than Windows Defender?

Comment: Edited above (answers: I don't any other antivirus/antispyware software installed; cpcmdrun.exe was launched via administrative cmd).

Comment: Sorry to see you got not answer on this, I haven't been through all the steps you have, but so far it's looking like the same symptoms.